# why is private final java.util.List< E > stack declared here as a variable?

Tags: java, list, stack

I am looking at the implementation of the Stack interface using a List as the underlying data structure and I never seen anything before being declared something like this. I usually see `java.util.something` as import. When would I use something like this ?

```
public class ListStack< E > implements Stack< E >
{
    private final java.util.List< E > stack;


    public ListStack( )
    {
        this.stack = new LinkedList< E >( );
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty( )
    {
        return this.stack.isEmpty( );
    }


    @Override
    public E peek( )
    {
        if ( this.stack.isEmpty( ) )
        {
            throw new EmptyStackException( );
        }
        return this.stack.get( this.stack.size( ) - 1 );
    }


    @Override
    public E pop( )
    {
        if ( this.stack.isEmpty( ) )
        {
            throw new EmptyStackException( );
        }
        return this.stack.remove( this.stack.size( ) - 1 );
    }


    @Override
    public void push( E element )
    {
        this.stack.add( this.stack.size( ), element );

    }


    @Override
    public int size( )
    {
        return this.stack.size( );
    }

}
```

stack interface

```
public interface Stack< E >
{
    public boolean isEmpty( );
    public E peek( );
    public E pop( );
    public void push( E element );
    public int size( );
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Why they used fully qualified type names rather than import?

Comment: You would have to ask the person that wrote the perfectly valid code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes and when you use something like this ? this is the first time I am seeing this

Comment: I think @JonKiparsky's deleted answer is right.

Comment: I didnt see his answer..

Comment: He stated, `"If I had to hazard a guess, I'd imagine that it might have to do with the existence of two classes called "List" in the core libraries. (The other is in awt). This might be a case of belting your suspenders."`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading the mind of the person who wrote the code.

Comment: there are only ListStack and Stack classes

Comment: Many languages allow you to access the same name in multiple ways, either with a simple identifier, or with multiple identifiers separated by `.` or `::` or the like.  In some cases, you need the longer name because there's another declaration that hides the simple identifier or makes it ambiguous.  But sometimes, you can use the longer name just to make things clearer for a reader, who then won't have to hunt around to figure out where the name comes from.  I have no idea why the author chose it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the perspective of just the declaration of the stack variable,

```
public class ListStack< E > implements Stack< E > {
    private final java.util.List< E > stack;
    ...
}
```

and

```
import java.util.List;
public class ListStack< E > implements Stack< E > {
    private final List< E > stack;
    ...
}
```

are, for all intents and purposes, identical.

You usually see fully qualified type declarations show up in variable declarations when there is something coming in on the imports that conflicts with the thing being declared.  Consider if I've got my own org.rekdev.List that I want to use for something else in ListStack but I need the regular java.util.List for the stack itself.  Now what?

If I try to just do the imports the compiler complains.

```
import org.rekdev.List;
import java.util.List;

public class ListStack< E > implements Stack< E > {
    private List< E > stack; 
    private List<E> myOwnList;
}

ListStack.java:2: org.rekdev.List is already defined in a single-type import
import java.util.List;
^
1 error
```

If I try to wildcard the problem away, the compiler complains more.

```
import org.rekdev.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ListStack< E > implements Stack< E > {
    private List< E > stack; 
    private List<E> myOwnList;
}

ListStack.java:5: reference to List is ambiguous, both class java.util.List in java.util and class org.rekdev.List in org.rekdev match
    private List< E > stack; 
            ^
ListStack.java:6: reference to List is ambiguous, both class java.util.List in java.util and class org.rekdev.List in org.rekdev match
    private List<E> myOwnList;
            ^
2 errors
```

The compiler is a cruel, cruel mistress that only accepts perfection.  Because there is more than one List in the compiler's scope, it is up to me to "disambiguate" the variable type declarations.  I could forget the imports and be all verbose everywhere...

```
public class ListStack< E > implements Stack< E > {
    private java.util.List< E > stack; 
    private org.rekdev.List<E> myOwnList;
}
```

That works, but thats a lot of typing.  Alternatively, I could import one and fully qualify the other.

```
import org.rekdev.*;

public class ListStack< E > implements Stack< E > {
    // This kid is java.util.List
    private java.util.List< E > stack; 
    // This kid is org.rekdev.List
    private List<E> myOwnList;
```

}

That is typically what you see.  The fully qualified one is some edge-case that is only happening once in the sourcefile allowing the import to bring as much of the namespace into scope as needed.  The mistress is happy.

Comment: you are the man!...thanks for taking the time to explain...I finally understand it